# Highstock Series Compare to First Day of Boundary Instead of Previous Day

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with the Highstock compare demo:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

The associated code of the percent compare is as follows:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    compare: 'percent'
  }
},
```

If we set the rangeSelector to 1m (one month), and assuming today is August 15, 2016, then the first entry displayed is Tuesday, July 12. The values are MSFT: 53.21, AAPL: 97.42, and GOOG: 720.64. The Tooltip shows percentage changes of +1.18%, +0.45%, and +0.78%, respectively, over the previous day. But the problem is that the values for the previous day (7/11/2016) are not shown. This is confusing to the user, in my opinion. What I want to do instead is give each of these starting values a percentage change of 0%, so the left-side of the graph always starts at the origin. How do I do this?

**UPDATE:** I was thinking along the lines of something like this:

```
events: {
  load: function(e) {
    set_new_min_y_data_points(e);
  }
}

// ...

function set_new_min_y_data_points(e) {

  for (var i = 0; i < e.target.series.length; ++i) {
    // By setting the first data point to the same 
    // value as the second data point, we ensure 
    // that the series starts at the origin.

    e.target.series[i].processedYData[0] = e.target.series[i].processedYData[1];
  }
}
```

...but this doesn't work. Even though the values of e.target.series[i].processedYData[0] are changed, the graph looks the same.

Comment: If you would like to change this behaviour, you may use tooltip pointFormatter or formatter and make your own logic in this function. Here you can see simple example of formatting function: http://jsfiddle.net/vd64fzdu/

Comment: That only modifies the tooltip. Is there a way to make the actual graph look different?